# MTA's poor reputation

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

Rather randomly only just started happening but when sending emails to certain people my emails are getting bounced back. I've set up domain keys and SPF records. I am with Just Host using an email program from their main control pannel. Thought purchasing a dedicated IP would solve it... i bought one and it hasnt, still comes up!! Have a feeling the email receipents are still reconising somthing to do with being on just host? The main server interface IP 173.236.44.98 can't be removed from the SPF... Only got a new IP yesterday so do i need to give it more time?

Full error message:

SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:

```
host in.mx.ifl.net [217.181.2.37]: 554-in5.mx.ifl.net
554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation.
If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/62093/554-sending-mtas-poor-reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a new IP address is what spammers do.  Cleaning up their act is what responsible sysadmins do.

Plugging your IP address into a [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=173.236.44.98) turns up links from several places indicating that it has hosted various types of malware in the past:

http://malc0de.com/database/index.php?search=173.236.44.98&IP=on
http://spam.bubble.ro/4225-assistance-needed/  (Click on show all headers)
http://lists.clean-mx.com/pipermail/viruswatch/20111116/028730.html ( lulibdem.com again)
http://support.clean-mx.de/clean-mx/viruses.php?ip=173.236.44.98&sort=ip%20desc

You are listed at [Spamcop](http://www.spamcop.net/w3m?action=checkblock&ip=173.236.44.98), [LashBack](http://www.lashback.com/blacklist/Delist.aspx?ip=173.236.44.98&h=fcb9bc72323047f31a2eab04d7bd71b9) and [BackScatterer](http://www.backscatterer.org/?ip=173.236.44.98).
[SenderBase](http://www.senderbase.org/senderbase_queries/detailip?search_string=173.236.44.98) and [SenderScore](https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=173.236.44.98) both think your reputation is poor.

Comment: the 173.236.44.98 is the server IP which is shared between several of people on 'just host', i didn't choose it! I have just started a new buisness and can assure you that everything i send out has been legit etc. I was told having my own 'fresh' IP address would stop other people blackening the servers record and thus stopping me sending emails out! thus purchasing my own IP. Feel ready to throw my laptop up the wall, so frustrating.

Comment: If you have another IP address, you can plug that one into all the same places I did to determine its reputation / blacklist status.  Even a "brand new" dedicated IP address can have a poor reputation from the previous owner.  Make sure you are actually sending your email from that IP address and not the one you listed in the question.  Inheriting a bad reputation from someone else's behaviour is frustrating but if it's dedicated solely to you then you can improve it. Lots of these reputation scores take a long time to improve (a month or more), blacklists can be fairly quick (hours to days).

Comment: Thanks, under the SPF section it wont let me remove the main server IP address. I previously added my new one hoping that it emails would source from new IP rather than old one. Think its has worked as emails appear to being sent from new ip, but still being blocked.... just bide my time then i suppose?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to ask ifl.net what they mean by that.

There is no standard that defines what "reputation" means.